MISP : Advanced auth keys are not enabled
I installed MISP in redhat using podman from this https://github.com/NUKIB/misp?tab=readme-ov-file.
Every think is working and I did the feed part and create user and stuff like this anyway everything is working.
Now I need to integrate the MISP with wazuh like to see what is the result. So I generate the Auth key but the prob is I keep getting this message in the top of the MISP dashboard:

Advanced auth keys are not enabled.


I ignore it and I took the key and add it in the script of integration in Wazuh https://github.com/karelumair/MISP-Wazuh-Integration/blob/main/custom-misp.py. Anyway I did what I have to do and nothing in showing in wazuh.
I think that the Auth Key is not working for me,
also in the listed API that I create it says that I've never used it means that the integration is not done well.
